# How to Access Static file logs inside an view in Django

Tags: python, django, file, logging, static

I want to log every Static Files request and the request IP address in Django.

In Console I am able to check the Static File Log, But I want access those logs inside an Django View with IP address of the request

Can Suggest an solution or any work around.

I am planning to server static files manually and perform logging.

Comment: Please explain what's stopping you from doing that.

Comment: I hesitated to use that method because, I had some confusion over URL, If i server manually the URL wont be an CDN URL, so I had a doubt whether the static files will be rendered in the external pages. But I tried that method and Its working, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I Created an view to serve static files manually using Django in-built 'serve' method, In which I get the IP Address of the Request using meta data of the Request